# Posterior Distribution

Tags: distributions, posterior, beta-distribution

I was just wondering what the posterior distribution would be for a prior density belonging to the beta family i.e. having a beta density and the likelihood function being the likelihood function of the Hardy Weinberg equilibrium.

Comment: The Hardy Weinberg equilibrium is not a likelihood function.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Hardy Weinberg equilibrium but from a brief look on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy%E2%80%93Weinberg_principle#Complete_generalization) it seems like it is using a multinomial distribution. The corresponding prior distribution would be a Dirichilet  (the multivariate extension of the beta distribution), which would get you to a conjugate posterior distribution that works out very nicely. [Here are some notes on it.](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~stephentu/writeups/dirichlet-conjugate-prior.pdf)